# how to set headers in axios patch request in react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

Can someone tell me what mistake I am making or  tell me how to set the header in axios patch request. when I am running the API through postman, everything is working fine but when I connect it with the front end, an error comes up saying that the JWT is not provided on the backend

here is the frond end code :

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';

const Loader = () => {
  const parmas = useParams();
  const { id } = parmas;
  console.log(id);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBags = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.patch('http://localhost:4001/public/verify', {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Token: id,
          },
        });

        console.log(res);
        console.log('CBM', { res });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchBags();
  }, []);
  return <div>this is loader</div>;
};

export default Loader;
```

below is my backend code:

```
export const verifyUser = async (data) => {
  const token1 = data.header("Token");

  try {
    const verified = jwt.verify(token1, getTokenSecret());
    console.log(verified)
    await userModel.verifyUser(verified);
    return {
      message: "success",
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Auth Service > verifyUser > ${error.toString()}`);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

this error is comming:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxvqf.png)

Comment: You're passing in the headers as the `data` argument, the headers should be the third argument (config). Look at the axios docs or peek the JSDoc in your IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro)

> axios.patch(url[, data[, config]])

As you can see you pass `config` in 3rd argument not 2nd.

```
const res = await axios.patch(
  'http://localhost:4001/public/verify',
  {}, // data (2nd argument)
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Token: id,
    },
  } // config (3rd argument)
)
```

Comment: i don't understand. please re write the above axios code? @bogdanoff

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I have updated my answer with snippet check it out.